# Display Hours on Vertical axis in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms, bar-chart

I have a graph in `SSRS` which displays info from a SP. The SP displays the duration of a process we have that runs daily. looks something like:

```
Date        |    Duration
2015/09/23  |    00:21:32
2015/09/22  |    00:28:43
2015/09/21  |    00:25:54
....
```

I am trying to display this information in a bar graph in SSRS so the dates are displayed on the bottom, and the bar represents the duration.

I have gotten it to display the time, but it is displayed as:

```
12:21 AM
```

Instead of:

```
00:21:32
```

I have't worked with the graphs on `SSRS` much, but when I try to convert to time or minutes it either doesn't change, or is just changed to `HH:MM:SS` and doesn't actually display anything.

Any help on the matter would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly after posting this I figured it out.

1. I converted the duration to `Time(0)` within the SP, and displayed the un-Aggregated version of the duration on the bar.
2. Then right clicked the vertical axis > properties > Number.
3. Then changed the Custom to HH:mm.

Is now properly displaying it as `00:20` up the side.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I had the same problem!